# Click to add item to current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations

I want users to be able to click on an item and went click it will add an item to their profile. a bit like a shopping cart

What I have done:

user model

```
has_many :items
```

item model

```
belongs_to :user
```

User views

```
<%= @items.each do |item| %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

How do I define my path when a user clicks?

How should is this stored in the database?

Comment: have you figured out how to achieve what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nested_form` for this kind of situation. You can checkout this [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) video to do this.

Or, you can implement `cocoon` [gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) to do this. It's quite good and the documentation is rich.